# Removing case sensitivity in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to ask a question in C but don't want case sensitivity on it. That way if someone inputs with uppercase or lowercase it will still be a correct answer.

Comment: Check out `tolower` or `strcasecmp`.

Comment: what are those?

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcasecmp and https://linux.die.net/man/3/tolower.